# Magento2 Code Migration Tool Issue with Custom Module Migration

Tags: magento2, code-migration

Anyone faced this error?

I'm trying to migrate a custom module.

When I run this command, I get the error below. Please advise.

```
php bin/migrate.php migrateModuleStructure source destination
```

---

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface in /var/www/code-migration-develop/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:50
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Found from ShaneVBG at https://github.com/magento/code-migration/issues/103

Add to app/etc/di.xml in @ ~ line 91

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface" type="Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json" />
```